# Google Cloud SQL Add Authorized Network

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Trying to connect to my Google Cloud SQL Instance. I'm at the part where I have to add an authorized subnet. I keep trying to add a new subnet but whenever I do the page tells me it couldn't complete the operation. I'm putting my IP address in CIDR format like "192.168.103.202/24", but it just won't get accepted. And I can't connect to the SQL instance without this piece. Help? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong???

if I try to connect to my google cloud sql instance without the subnet added I get the error:
I keep getting the error 'If Google Cloud SQL rejects the connection, for example, because the IP address your client is connecting from is not authorized, the error you receive will be'

which is expected as per the docs

reference:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access_control

Answer (score 10, accepted):

192.168.103.202 is your internal IP address, which is not publicly accessible, you need to enter your public IP address into the authorized network dialog.

The easiest way to get this is to enter "whats my ip" into Google and it will tell you "Your public IP address is x.x.x.x".